# How to get binary image data from IntPtr (look alike multipart/form-data)

Tags: c#, .net-core

Let's say:

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[1024 * 100];
Marshal.Copy(nET_DVR_XML_CONFIG_OUTPUT.lpOutBuffer, b, 0, 1024 * 100);
string responseMsg = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);
            
//so string responseMsg basically like this.
string responseMsg = @"Content-Type:multipart/form-data;boundary=MIME_boundary
--MIME_boundary
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length:1629
{
    "requestURL":   "/ISAPI/Intelligent/FDLib/FDSearch?format=json",
    "statusCode":   1
}
--MIME_boundary
Content-Type:image/jpeg
Content-Length:20455

???? ►JFIF ☺☺☺ ? ?  ??♥rExif  (much more binary data.....)

--MIME_boundary"; //End of string
```

How do I get just the image binary data only? Just to make it more clear, `nET_DVR_XML_CONFIG_OUTPUT.lpOutBuffer` is IntPtr send by the device after I send a request through ISAPI.

Comment: you need to parse this response to get the required data

Comment: @viveknuna is not wrong but more tags would be helpful.  ***get the data*** using WHAT?  Are you talking about asp.net ..?  .. core3? .. client? .. server? ..  giving more information (don't assume that people know) will get you a more precise answer.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas .netcore. I wish I can add more tags, unfortunately I don't have enough reputation to do so.

Comment: @standleypeter I added the tag. We don't put anything that can be a tag in the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your response is a [Multi-part MIME message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/troubleshoot/administration/multipart-mixed-mime-message-format).

Your first challenge is to parse the MIME parts.  Here are two good resources:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mime.contenttype.boundary
- https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/2b481f/processing-multipart-mime-in-asp-net-web-api/

The second MIME message part is clearly a binary .jpeg file (hence the [JFIF header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG_File_Interchange_Format)).  You should be able to treat it as a .Net "string", and simply convert it to a byte array:

```
byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input);
```

The resulting byte array is your JPEG image.

Comment: I am not really sure how am I able to separate the boundary and get only the image byte data.

Comment: Like I said - you just need to read the "MIME Part". It's really that simple.  Unfortunately, the Microsoft link didn't copy/paste correctly.  Sorry - I just fixed it.  Please read the two links I cited.  You can also Google for "C# Mime Multipart", or install a C# library like [MimeKit](http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/N_MimeKit.htm): https://stackoverflow.com/a/46474417/421195.

Comment: thank you for the MimeKit Library suggestion. It solved my problem. cheers.